# parametros con # nodejs

Tags: nodejs

Tengo una aplicación en HMVC y voy a migrarla de PHP a NodeJS de forma parcial.
Necesito que NodeJs me lea la siguiente dirección https://localhost/#servicios/orden/detalle, el símbolo (#) no me lo toma como parámetro, necesito que lo haga, para cargar el módulo correspondiente a esa ruta.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
const url = require('url');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('config/localhost.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync( 'config/localhost.crt' ),
    ca: fs.readFileSync( 'config/localhost.crt' )
};

app.get('/', function(request, response){
    var URI = url.parse(request.url); 
    var href = URI.hash.replace('#', '');
    fs.readFile('.' + href + '/view/index.html', function(err, html){
        response.write(html);
        response.end();
    });
});

https.createServer(options, app).listen(4430);
```

El problema es que URI.hash me lo retorna como undefined

Answer (score 1):

el problema es que cuando le asignas el valor a `var URI = url.parse(request.url);`
llega con el valor de `/`, luego, `var href = URI.hash.replace('#', '');`, como URI no posee valor, te arroja un undefined. El carácter `#` elimina por algún motivo, todo lo que venga después. Se me ocurre que en vez de poner `#` pongas su representación `%23` u otro carácter especial, luego se podría reemplazar en el código como indico a continuación:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.end("Esta es la respuesta del API")

    var URI = url.parse(req.url, true);

    console.log('URI.pathname: ',URI.pathname)

    var path = URI.pathname;
    var trimmedPath = path.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g, '').replace('%23', '#');

    console.log('req.url: ',req.url)
    console.log('trimmedPath: ',trimmedPath)
})
```

la respuesta ante el siguiente CURL: `curl http://localhost:3000/%23servicios/orden/detalle`

es:

```
Server iniciado: http://localhost:3000
URI.pathname:  /%23servicios/orden/detalle
req.url:  /%23servicios/orden/detalle
trimmedPath:  #servicios/orden/detalle
```

Espero que te haya ayudado